# Ada: select then abort statement

Tags: synchronization, task, ada

I have a question regarding the "select then abort" language construct in Ada. The task I'm using looks something like:

```
select
  delay 1.0;
  do something with the partial result;
then abort
  loop 
    ...
    long calculation
    ...
    entry call to other task;
    ...
  end loop;
end select;
```

Can the code in the abort branch be aborted anywhere or only at certain points like delay statements or entry calls?
In my program the code in the abort branch performs a long calculation and when aborted the partial calculated result is still useful. But if the code can be interrupted anywhere the problem of data inconsistencies arises.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The abort can happen anywhere, except in an abort deferred region. A protected operation is an abort deferred region, so you can store your partial results inside a protected object.

Comment: [Here](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/docs/95style/html/sec_6/6-3-3.html) they talk about that a task can only be aborted at abort completion points. So are you sure that your answer is correct?

Comment: The requirement is that the aborted construct completes _no later_ than the next abort completion point ([RM:9.8(15)](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12aarm/html/AA-9-8.html), and the implementation note in 19.b says "Implementations may of course check for abort more often than at each abort completion point; ideally, a fully preemptive implementation of abort will be provided. If preemptive abort is not supported in a given environment, then supporting the checking for abort as part of subprogram calls and loop iterations might be a useful option."

Comment: Any reasonably modern OS and compiler will support preemptive abort. If your platform is limited, you should check your compiler documentation for the exact behaviour.

Comment: I don't think you are right. I works as described in the link above.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information at [adaic.org](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/docs/craft/html/ch19.htm#19.4), the part in between `then abort` and `end select` can be aborted anywhere.